# How to solve and plot this 2nd order non linear ODE?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Is this the correct way to plot the solution of this ODE from $(-8, 8)$?

$$y'' - (1 - (y')^2)y' + y = 0$$

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] - (1 - y'[x]^2) y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1,  y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -8, 8}]

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -8, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: To my mind it's perfect, better than `NDSolveValue` in ways I've explained elsewhere, and exactly the form shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works, but technically it is not elegant. Despite the fact that there is only one solution, NDSolve returns a list of a list with the solution, so actually you have to use the Part function for selecting it.

In Mathematica 10, you can use NDSolveValue, which returns the solution itself:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - (1 - y'[x]^2) y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -8, 8}]

(*InterpolatingFunction[{{-8., 8.}}, <>]*)
```

You can use this function for anything you want, e.g.

```
Plot[sol[x], {x, -8, 8}]
```

which returns your graph.